# How do i swap the first word of a line with the last word in a line

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed

I was trying to replace the first word in a line with the last word in a line using a sed command i=but i can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: In every line, or a specific line.  If so which line?

Answer (score 6):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{ t=$1; $1=$NF; $NF=t; print}'
```

This will:

- `t=$1` - set `t` to the first word
- `$1=$NF` - set the first word to the last word
- `$NF=t` - set the last word to the first word
- `print` - print the new line.

---

```
$ echo 'one two three four five six' | awk '{ f=$1; l=$NF; $1=l; $NF=f; print}'
six two three four five one
```

Comment: @Kusalananda: Thanks.  Didn't think of it.

Comment: Slightly shorter : `awk '{ t=$1; $1=$NF; $NF=t}1'`

Answer (score 4):

Using Perl, and assuming whitespace delimited input and space-delimited output:

```
perl -ape '($F[0],$F[-1])=($F[-1],$F[0]);$_="@F\n"'
```

Testure:

```
$ printf 'Cleanse Fold and Manipulate\n' | perl -ape '($F[0],$F[-1])=($F[-1],$F[0]);$_="@F\n"'
Manipulate Fold and Cleanse
```

The Perl code, using `-a` to split the input on whitespace into the array `@F`, simply swaps the two elements at the start and end of that array before joining the resulting list with spaces, adding a newline at the end.

A shorter Perl variant that matches the first and last words and swaps them in a substitution (this assumes that there are no flanking whitespace in the input though):

```
perl -pe 's/^(\w*)(.*?)(\w*)$/$3$2$1/'
```

The middle bit, `.*?`, matches the middle of the string non-greedily. We couldn't have done this this easily with `sed` as there is no non-greedy modifier like that `?` after `.*`.

Comment: Or, allowing for leading trailing whitespace: `perl -pe 's/^(\s*)(\S+)(.+?)(\S+)(\s*)$/$1$4$3$2$5/'` -- note the middle bit has at least 1 char to account for separate first/last words.

Answer (score 1):

Semi-serious answer: it's not you, you are fine. The problem is totally in `sed`'s `s///` command's verbosity (compare this with the alternative answers):

```
$ echo "Hello some good world!" |
sed 's/\(^[^[:space:]]\+\)\([[:space:]].*[[:space:]]\|[[:space:]]\+\)\([^[:space:]]\+$\)/\3\2\1/'
world! some good Hello
```

We may also want to swap the first and the last words even if we have space characters before the first and/or after the latter (thanks to comments and other answers):

```
$ echo "  Hello some   good world!  " |
sed 's/^\([[:space:]]*\)\([^[:space:]]\+\)\([[:space:]].*[[:space:]]\|[[:space:]]\+\)\([^[:space:]]\+\)\([[:space:]]*\)$/\1\4\3\2\5/'
  world! some   good Hello
```

However, these commands use some non-POSIX GNU extensions to the BRE - Basic Regular Expression - syntax (namely, `+` and `|`).
A (more portable) command that satisfies the POSIX standard while keeping the convenience of alternation (`|`) would require Extended regular expressions. For example, using GNU `sed` with the `--posix` option (which disables GNU extensions - not actually required):

```
$ echo "  Hello some   good world!  " |
sed --posix -E 's/^([[:space:]]*)([^[:space:]]{1,})([[:space:]].*[[:space:]]|[[:space:]]{1,})([^[:space:]]{1,})([[:space:]]*)$/\1\4\3\2\5/'
  world! some   good Hello
```

Note, however, that POSIX ERE syntax does not include backreferences. This command, too, will require an implementation with extensions to succeed.

Comment: Will not destroy the original whitespace. +1